# passing variables in cur.executescript

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Currently I have the following code which checks if tablename `"Company"` exists in the database, and then creates the table with the given fields.

```
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Company;
CREATE TABLE Company (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR2  
)
''')
```

I want to make this query generic as in, instead of just using `"Company"` in my query, I need to take the names from a list. Is it possible to pass a variable in the query instead of passing `"Company"` in this example.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `cur.executescript('''... IF EXISTS %s; CREATE ...''' % my_variable)`?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to pass a variable table name (or column name) to sqlite. (And since `executescript` takes exactly one argument, it's not possible to pass a variable to `executescript`).

You could build the query before the execute and pass that variable to `executescript`.

And of course if you take the table names from a list, it seems likely you will have to take the column names too!

Comment: yes that's how you need to do it, but careful about where the variables for this come from as you risk SQL injection.